# How to run full archive Geth to sync from the beginning?

Tags: go-ethereum, genesis

I've started `v1.12.0` Geth with following flags:

```
            "--mainnet",
            "--datadir=/root/.ethereum/mainnet-geth",
            "--syncmode=full",
            "--gcmode=archive",
            "--cache=65536",
            "--http",
            "--http.addr=0.0.0.0",
            "--http.corsdomain=*",
            "--http.vhosts=*",
            "--http.port=8545",
            "--http.api=engine,eth,net,web3,admin,debug,personal,txpool",
            "--ws",
            "--ws.addr=0.0.0.0",
            "--ws.origins=*",
            "--ws.port=8546",
            "--ws.api=engine,eth,net,web3,admin,debug,personal,miner,txpool",
            "--port=30303",
            "--txlookuplimit=0",
            "--rpc.allow-unprotected-txs",
            "--cache.preimages",
            "--authrpc.port=8551",
            "--authrpc.jwtsecret=/root/.ethereum/jwt.secret",
```

In the logs I can see:

> New local node record lines

started from *seq=1,692,800,175,905*, and after 7 days it's *seq=1,692,800,176,877*.

Also I'm getting warnings:

> Beacon client online, but never received consensus updates. Please ensure your beacon client is operational to follow the chain!

I am running lighthouse also, but it's latest beacon slot at the moment is 3,463,520 (out of 7mil currently on chain).

Does it mean I need to wait for Lighthouse to be in sync with the network or I need to run Geth with some special flags in order to tell it to sync blocks which happened before The Merge?